# NGINX suddenly redirects everything to main domain

Tags: nginx

After weeks of working perfectly, NGINX started redirecting everything to the main domain. I set it up so that numerical subdomains would be proxied to a specific port like this : 5555.example.com -> example.com:5555. The NGINX version was not updated nor has the configuration files been changed, but now, all subdomains get redirected to the main domain (5555.example.com gets instantly changed to example.com and I reach the main domain).

Here's the content of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
      listen [::]:80;
      listen 80;
      server_name "~^(www\.)?(?<port_subdomain>\d{4})\.example\.com$";

      location / {
        resolver 10.33.1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://example.com:$port_subdomain;
      }
    }

    server {
      listen [::]:80;
      listen 80;
      server_name ~^(www\.)?example\.com$;

      location / {
        resolver 10.33.1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8502;
      }
    }
}
```

When I run

```
nginx -t
```

I get

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

There is an error in the logs, but from what I see, that error has been popping up since I installed NGINX :

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: XXX.XX.XXX.XX, server: ~^(?<port_subdomain>[0-9]*)\.example\.com$, 
request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LPZb6nq HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://XX.XX.X.XX:5555/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LPZb6nq", 
host: "5555.example.com", referrer: "http://5555.example.com/"
```

Comment: Why do you think that the redirect comes from nginx, not from your upstream?

Comment: It's exactly what I'm starting to think. I don't have access to the upstream server, trying to figure things out with the sys admins atm.

Comment: It's certainly not an nginx problem, since there's nothing in your config that can emit a redirect.